# Jboss Studio Developer starting ticket-monster example, errors with database

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, h2

I'm learning now how to make first application in JBoss Developer Studio I have read all tutorial about their example of ticket-monster application I have configured maven as they said, Ive downloaded project from their git repository and improted this to my project. I have run project and everythins is working but there are problems with H2 database. When i go to admin console
localhost:8080/h2console Its working and i see new added columns with records as it is in import.sql file in project but in Console i get errors, and half of the pages in project dont work. In console i have got this errors and i dont know how to solve them.

```
17:19:18,267 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider

17:19:18,468 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

17:19:18,474 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work

17:19:18,640 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory

17:19:18,644 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

17:19:18,688 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54 HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1

17:19:19,135 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Appearance drop constraint FK_8s2lbwy173deq6xhtap48djlb

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "APPEARANCE" not found; SQL statement: alter table Appearance drop constraint FK_8s2lbwy173deq6xhtap48djlb [42102-168]

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Appearance drop constraint FK_5xl8g6pwd699frupjk2bp03ks

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "APPEARANCE" not found; SQL statement: alter table Appearance drop constraint FK_5xl8g6pwd699frupjk2bp03ks [42102-168]

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Booking drop constraint FK_leaf9xapkf0xcql0rj1ju6a3r

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "BOOKING" not found; SQL statement:alter table Booking drop constraint FK_leaf9xapkf0xcql0rj1ju6a3r [42102-168]

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Event drop constraint FK_5nymmio04sew5y7o7wvtv82na

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "EVENT" not found; SQL statement:alter table Event drop constraint FK_5nymmio04sew5y7o7wvtv82na [42102-168]

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Event drop constraint FK_cck2yno71efp1ghlfme4ophux

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "EVENT" not found; SQL statement:alter table Event drop constraint FK_cck2yno71efp1ghlfme4ophux [42102-168]

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Performance drop constraint FK_2ad0jk30a6hi0twn2xxso6g71

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "PERFORMANCE" not found; SQL statement:alter table Performance drop constraint FK_2ad0jk30a6hi0twn2xxso6g71 [42102-168]

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Section drop constraint FK_bpuwo340e2jxwlwyf8qai3gql

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "SECTION" not found; SQL statement:alter table Section drop constraint FK_bpuwo340e2jxwlwyf8qai3gql [42102-168]

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table SectionAllocation drop constraint FK_5dwueehoc18d429a6ma2e7t6

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "SECTIONALLOCATION" not found; SQL statement:alter table SectionAllocation drop constraint FK_5dwueehoc18d429a6ma2e7t6 [42102-168]

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table SectionAllocation drop constraint FK_ds4sl29sqh0snk7hw733p3fx0

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "SECTIONALLOCATION" not found; SQL statement:alter table SectionAllocation drop constraint FK_ds4sl29sqh0snk7hw733p3fx0 [42102-168]

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Ticket drop constraint FK_pdk8eed2puqot8lx8c90ledjn

17:19:19,135 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "TICKET" not found; SQL statement:alter table Ticket drop constraint FK_pdk8eed2puqot8lx8c90ledjn [42102-168]

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Ticket drop constraint FK_jvudijc5qlti0547g3fuoctis

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "TICKET" not found; SQL statement:alter table Ticket drop constraint FK_jvudijc5qlti0547g3fuoctis [42102-168]

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Ticket drop constraint FK_fphjem4g2orlpfeabeuxkhycx

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "TICKET" not found; SQL statement:alter table Ticket drop constraint FK_fphjem4g2orlpfeabeuxkhycx [42102-168]

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table TicketPrice drop constraint FK_b4y5fuevgavs3drls31ni6wd3

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "TICKETPRICE" not found; SQL statement:alter table TicketPrice drop constraint FK_b4y5fuevgavs3drls31ni6wd3 [42102-168]

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table TicketPrice drop constraint FK_ntne1lqkfmtmke809budx5itq

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "TICKETPRICE" not found; SQL statement:alter table TicketPrice drop constraint FK_ntne1lqkfmtmke809budx5itq [42102-168]

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table TicketPrice drop constraint FK_7o36hepy47tlyk1ta3ksix9fv

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "TICKETPRICE" not found; SQL statement:alter table TicketPrice drop constraint FK_7o36hepy47tlyk1ta3ksix9fv [42102-168]

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Venue drop constraint FK_2c9wphvw1mi32yr614p4u7cuf

17:19:19,150 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) Table "VENUE" not found; SQL statement:alter table Venue drop constraint FK_2c9wphvw1mi32yr614p4u7cuf [42102-168]

17:19:19,213 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000230: Schema export complete

17:19:19,716 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JBAS018210: Register web context: /demo

17:19:19,770 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "h2console.war" (runtime-name : "h2console.war")

17:19:19,770 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "demo.war" (runtime-name : "demo.war")

17:19:19,771 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)        JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service     jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http:    org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service    jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use:   bind localhost/127.0.0.1:9990
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory database of H2 has another instance running. So check if there's another process of java.exe running in your machine from a previous h2, that's causing issues with the binding to same port.Terminate that process and re-run the application you may not get the error.